# Reset Audio Waveform in Pitivi

Tags: video-editor, audio-recording, pitivi

I have some clips that I am editing and every time I split the clips to remove certain sections from them, the audio waveform is screwed and it gets really difficult to know the audio start locations.

Is there a way to reset the Audio Waveform after the clip splits?

Here is a gif.

[image]

Here are my Pitivi version details.

```
Version 2021.05
GES 1.18.3.0
GTK+ 3.24
GStreamer 1.18.3.0
```

I also submitted this as an issue - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pitivi/-/issues/2602

Comment: Does it happen with the latest version?

Comment: Yes. Latest version as well. I added my version details to the question.

Comment: @Community I added a gif highlighting the issue.